# Undo/Redo Operation doesn't work with Bold,italic, Background and Foreground text color in UITextview

Tags: ios, iphone, uitextview, nsattributedstring, nsundomanager

As User enter some text in **UITextview**, User applies some operation like Bold, italic, Underline, Bullet, Background and Foreground color to the specific text.When Undo/redo operation is applied, it will erase the whole word instead of eliminating **bold**/*italic* or foreground/background color of the text in textview.

Here's the code for it.

```
 [[txtViewNote undoManager] undo]; //Button Action Method for Undo
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found third party code which perfectly meet my requirements i.e. to use [This Text Editor](https://github.com/nnhubbard/ZSSRichTextEditor)
which gives bullet,numbered,**bold**,*italic* and so on in simple way.